# cyberoam vpn client stops browsing for name based website but IP based works

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have cyberoam vpn-server and I am using open vpn client to connect with cyberoam vpn-server. As soon as I connect on vpn my url-based browsing totally stops but my IP based browsing works.

Many suggestions to go to "network manager-> IP4->Use this connection only for resource of this network" 
I have installed gnome open vpn manager. It does not works in my case because cyberroam vpn-connection is not even visiable under network manager.

This pdf file link is official link from cyberoam to connect over vpn.

https://kb.cyberoam.com/redirfile.asp?id=6960

Comment: It's a DNS problem.

Answer (score 0):

check "/etc/resolve.conf file" maybe this file dont have any DNS Server entry.
Thats why name base site are not working. There can be another issue. Nameserver which is mentions in the resolve.conf file not reachable via VPN network.

Comment: This file does not exists

Answer (score 0):

You can create this file with `vim`/`vi`/`nano` as below

```
sudo vi /etc/resolve.conf
```

press <kbd>i</kbd> and insert name server entry in this format

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver "second name server IP"
```

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then type `:wq` to save and exit.